# The current URL, about/{% url 'home' %}, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Hello one newbie question regarding django-urls. I have an error when I am trying to get back from mine contact, about page or any other to mine home page.
This is the Error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in tryDjango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='home']
^about/$ [name='about']
^profile/$ [name='profile']
^contact/$ [name='contact']
^checkout/$ [name='checkout']
^accounts/
^admin/
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, about/{% url 'home' %}, didn't match any of these.
```

Mine root/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'profiles.views.home', name='home'),
    #url(r'^testhome/$', 'profiles.views.testhome', name='testhome'),
    url(r'^about/$', 'profiles.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^profile/$', 'profiles.views.profile', name='profile'),
    url(r'^contact/$', 'contact.views.contact', name='contact'),
    url(r'^checkout/$', 'checkout.views.checkout', name='checkout'),
    (r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),


    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Can someone explain to me where am I mistaking here, I guess it is visible from space, but I am rely confused.
Tank you.

Comment: Can you show the template as well?

Comment: [base.html](http://ur1.ca/jsem6), and mine [home.html](http://ur1.ca/jsemk)

Comment: How about the template in which `about/{% url 'home' %}` appears?

Comment: Sory, here [navbar.html](http://ur1.ca/jsen0)

Comment: It looks like you've made a mistake with Enter on the 18 line. Remove it and everything will be fine.

Comment: in mine navbar.html or somewhere else?

Comment: @Jacqueminot ... I believe newlines are valid in template tags. I could be totally wrong.

Comment: He is wright, I have typed one enter more, then I should have, tnx ppl

Comment: Yes in navbar.html.
@rnevius newlines make loading of page is correct, but redirecting by that invalid url is impossible.

Comment: everything is working now, tank you, I will be more careful second  time.